# Building Pandas Dataframe of unevaluated dask expressions

Tags: python, pandas, dask

I have a running script which opens many CSV file (containing series thus each only one column of data) does some calculations and extracts features.
Those features get saved in two existing Pandas Dataframes.

```
pdDF1.loc[pandas.to_datetime(somestring[-22:-7]),somestring[-7:-4]] = feat1
pdDF2.loc[pandas.to_datetime(somestring[-22:-7]),somestring[-7:-4]] = feat2
```

For parralelization I want to have the feature calculation step done in dask (what is already fine running).
The result in dask is a tuple of two features of the following type

```
(dask.array<sqrt, shape=(), dtype=float64, chunksize=()>,
 dask.array<mean_agg-aggregate, shape=(), dtype=float64, chunksize=()>)
```

I want to insert the first tuple element into one column of a Pandas Dataframe and the other tuple's element in another column of another Dataframe (like code sample above). But always when inserting into the Pandas Dataframe the dask results got calculated.

What I want to do is: First grow the complete Pandas Dataframe and then evaluate all dask entries with one compute call.
How can that be done? Thanks in advance.

Comment: It sounds like you want to concat the results of all the dask computations. You do not want to build the pandas DataFrame piecemeal.

Comment: @AndyHayden It is a bit more complicated: Depending on the CVS-Filename the row and column in the pandas DataFrame is selected and the the dask computed features are to be inserted. I'd like to build the pdas DataFrame piecewise (as I think it is the only way) and then compute all entries with one dask.compute command.

Comment: Perhaps I'm missing something, but I don't see a reason to store dask values in a pandas dataframe. Could you instead build a list of results `results = [...]`, call `dask.compute(results)` and insert that in the dataframe? If you make a https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve it'll be easier to help.

Comment: @TomAugspurger You are right, and this is the way, I actually do it - a list of dask, computing and then postprocessing. I was hoping to skip that intermediate step on one hand and further I'm interested why that automated evaluation when inserting into a dataframe happens

Comment: My guess is that pandas is triggering dask's array protocol, and converting the lazy results into concrete values with something like `np.array([list of dask objects])`.